# Did "Number Five" really act differently from his father?

Tags: gene-wolfe, the-fifth-head-of-cerberus

In the story *The Fifth Head of Cerberus*, the protagonist - whose real name is never mentioned, so I'll just call him "Number Five" as his father and aunt do - is essentially an experiment of his father's. Towards the end of the story he learns that he is

> a cloned duplicate of his father, in fact part of a long sequence of such duplicates.

The visiting Dr Marsch describes the experiment as like "relaxation", in which approximations are made increasingly accurate by iteration. He says that "Number Five" and his father are now essentially one individual - an observation which seems supported by the close physical resemblance between them, noted throughout the story and especially strong towards the end.

But the implication of the final part of the story, or at least the implication I picked up, is that "Number Five" turns out *not* to be so much like his father after all. In fact, he

> kills his father, and serves long years in a labour camp for this crime.

Was his father expecting this, and did he do the same thing to his own father? **By doing what he did, is "Number Five" essentially conforming to his father's intent and carrying on the same family tradition? Or did he dramatically diverge from the expected behaviour of his family** (and if so, why - what influences on his life made him so different from his father and grandfather?)?

I've only read the story once, and the answer to this important issue has evaded me. But I suspect that a close reading of the text, and especially the parts which refer to the protagonist's father/ancestors and his relationship with them, will provide enough evidence to piece together the answer.